# How can I select if Date column is as same as current year

Tags: sql

This is my `Student` table

```
Id(int) | Name(varchar) | registerDate(Date)
1         John            2012-01-01
```

How can I write the appropriate query to check if the person's `registerDate` value is as same as current year (2012)?

Comment: `YEAR(registerDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())`

Comment: The above is for MySQL. MS SQL Server uses `GETDATE()`. Please post the RDBMS you're using.

Comment: Thank you @Michael but why didn't you send it as an answer so I could accept it :) Thank you for your help.

Comment: This question comes up often so i went looking for a duplicate question to link to instead  I never found a suitable one. But I don't particularly need the points anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE YEAR(registerDate) = YEAR(getdate())
```

Answer (score 6):

The most direct solution would be to use the `YEAR` or `DATEPART` function in whatever flavor of SQL you're using. This will probably meet your needs but keep in mind that this approach does not allow you to use an index if you're searching the table for matches. In this case, it would be more efficient to use the `BETWEEN` operator.

e.g.

```
SELECT id, name, registerDate 
FROM Student 
WHERE registerDate BETWEEN 2012-01-01 and 2012-12-31
```

How you would generate the first and last day of the current year will vary by SQL flavor.

Because you're using a range, and index can be utilized. If you were using a function to calculate the year for each row, it would need to be computed for each row in the table instead of seeking directly to the relevant rows.

Comment: Plus one for a much more thorough answer than my own :)

Answer (score 3):

If by chance your flavor of sql is Microsoft TSql then this works:

```
SELECT  * FROM Student Where datepart(yy,registerDate) = datepart(yy,GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE registerDate=YEAR(CURDATE())
```